# append an array with values python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, word2vec

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Body_Q': [['p', 'starting', 'work', 'hobby', 'project', 'python'], ['p', 'read', 'several', 'documentation', 'already']],
        'Price': [['p', 'use', 'buildbot', 'hudson', 'jython', 'development'], ['p', 'sure', 'level', 'knowledge', 'apologize', 'answer']],
        'A': ['NaN', 'NaN'],
        'Q': ['NaN', 'NaN']
        })
```

My idea is to loop on every sentence, then in every word and catch Words vector from Word2vec. Then it want to store every vector from every word in a sentence in an array.

I've made the following code:

```
# first loop
for index, row in df_train.iterrows():
    df_train.iloc[index]['A'] = []
    #second loop
    for word in df_train.iloc[index]['Body_A']:
      # We check if the word is in the vocab to get vectors
      if word in model.vocab:
        # if yes I want to catch them and put them inside my array
        np.append(df_train.iloc[index]['A'], model[word])
    df_train.iloc[index]['Q'] = []
    for word in df_train.iloc[index]['Body_Q']:
      if word in model.vocab:
        np.append(df_train.iloc[index]['Q'], model[word])
    print(df_train.iloc[index]['A'])
```

But for a reason I can't understand my output is always fill with nan values:

```
nan
nan
nan
nan
...
```

I don't understand what I could go wrong. Could you please tell me more?

Comment: Where do you get NaNs from (Exact line of code)? Don't hesitate to put "print" everywhere if you don't have a debugger. :)

Comment: where is the sentence?

Comment: Unable to repeat your question, please replace the code in the model part with the input value.

Comment: Where is 'Body_A' defined in the data frame?